# An outline/sharp transition in a fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I would like to create a sharp transition effect between pixels in my fragment shader, but I'm not sure how I could do this.

In my vertex shader I have a `varying float x;` and in my fragment shader I use this value to set the opacity of the color. I quantize the current value to produce a layering effect. What I'd like to do is at a very minimal level of the effect to produce a distinct border (a different color entirely). For example, if `x>0.1` and for any neighboring pixel `x<0.1` then the resulting color should be black.

It don't see any way in GLSL to gain access to neighbouring pixels (I could be wrong). How could I achieve such an effect. I'm limited to OpenGL-ES2.0 (though if not possible at all on this version, then any solution would be helpful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot access neighboring pixels, this is due to the fact that there is no guarantee which order the pixels are written, they are all drawn in parallel. If you could access neighboring pixels in the framebuffer you would get inconsistent results.

However you can do this in a post-process if you want. Draw your whole scene into a framebuffer texture, and then draw that texture to the screen with a filtering shader.

When drawing from a texture in your shader you can sample neighboring texels all you want, so you could easily compare the delta between two neighboring texels.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since it seems very few ES devices actually support standard derivatives as in Pivot's answer (which will hopefully be the correct answer in a few years time).

Answer (score 3):

If your OpenGL ES implementation supports the [`OES_standard_derivatives`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_standard_derivatives.txt) extension, you can get the rate of change of your variable by forward/backward differencing with neighboring pixels in the 2×2 quad being shaded:

```
float outline(float t, float threshold, float width)
{
    return clamp(width - abs(threshold - t) / fwidth(t), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This function returns the coverage for a line of the specified width where `t` ≈ `threshold`, using `fwidth` to determine how far it is from the cutoff. Note that `fwidth(t)` is equivalent to `abs(dFdx(t)) + abs(dFdy(t))` and calculates the width in [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), which may overfatten diagonal lines. If you prefer [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```
float outline(float t, float threshold, float width)
{
    float dx = dFdx(t);
    float dy = dFdy(t);
    float ewidth = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return clamp(width - abs(threshold - t) / ewidth, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: This is great. I wonder why these functions weren't included in ES by default (since they've existed since 1.10 in the full spec). I just need to a find a reference now saying on which devices such extensions are supported.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Because ES 2.0 has to support as broad a range of hardware as possible. And explicit derivatives aren't supported by everything that ES 2.0 currently supports.

Comment: @Pivot This question might come a little bit late, but what values are you actually putting in for t, threshold and width? I expect width to be the desired width of the outline? I would be very grateful for an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pivot's implementation based on derivatives, you can grab neighboring pixels from a source image using an offset based on the pixel dimensions of that source. The inverse of the width or height in pixels is the offset from the current texture coordinate that you'll need to use here.

For example, here is a vertex shader I've used to calculate these offsets for the eight pixels that surround a central one:

```
 attribute vec4 position;
 attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

 uniform highp float texelWidth; 
 uniform highp float texelHeight; 

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 rightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 topTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topRightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomRightTextureCoordinate;

 void main()
 {
     gl_Position = position;

     vec2 widthStep = vec2(texelWidth, 0.0);
     vec2 heightStep = vec2(0.0, texelHeight);
     vec2 widthHeightStep = vec2(texelWidth, texelHeight);
     vec2 widthNegativeHeightStep = vec2(texelWidth, -texelHeight);

     textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
     leftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - widthStep;
     rightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + widthStep;

     topTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - heightStep;
     topLeftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - widthHeightStep;
     topRightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + widthNegativeHeightStep;

     bottomTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + heightStep;
     bottomLeftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - widthNegativeHeightStep;
     bottomRightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + widthHeightStep;
 }
```

and here's a fragment shader that uses this to perform Sobel edge detection:

```
 precision mediump float;

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 rightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 topTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topRightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomRightTextureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 void main()
 {
    float bottomLeftIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomLeftTextureCoordinate).r;
    float topRightIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topRightTextureCoordinate).r;
    float topLeftIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topLeftTextureCoordinate).r;
    float bottomRightIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomRightTextureCoordinate).r;
    float leftIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, leftTextureCoordinate).r;
    float rightIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, rightTextureCoordinate).r;
    float bottomIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).r;
    float topIntensity = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topTextureCoordinate).r;
    float h = -topLeftIntensity - 2.0 * topIntensity - topRightIntensity + bottomLeftIntensity + 2.0 * bottomIntensity + bottomRightIntensity;
    float v = -bottomLeftIntensity - 2.0 * leftIntensity - topLeftIntensity + bottomRightIntensity + 2.0 * rightIntensity + topRightIntensity;

    float mag = length(vec2(h, v));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(mag), 1.0);
 }
```

I pass in the `texelWidth` and `texelHeight` uniforms, which are 1/width and 1/height of the image, respectively. This does require you to track the input image width and height, but it should work on all OpenGL ES devices, not just those with the derivative extensions.

I do the texture offset calculations in the vertex shader for two reasons: so that offset calculations only need to be performed once per vertex instead of once per fragment, and more importantly because some of the tile-based deferred renderers react very poorly to dependent texture reads where texture offsets are calculated in a fragment shader. The performance can be up to 20X higher for a shader program that removes these dependent texture reads on these devices.

Comment: This is good. I have however read that dynamically modifying a texture is implemented poorly on some devices -- compared to dynamic vertex attributes.  I think a dynamic texture would sever me better, but I'm worried about these bad devices.